# Firebase data according data safety section

Tags: google-play, firebase-security

Recently Google play announced data section form to fill up collected or shared data. Firebase also added a [blog](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/play-data-disclosure#firebase-user-agent) regarding it. Now I am bit confused.

Case1 Suppose firebase authentication stores ip address or name which I don't store in my database What should I do. Do I need to add I am taking name or something like that.

Case2 I am using firestore and storage and all writes are off. Then also I need to add something like firebase agent and what is firebase user agent and in which data category it will be added

Case3 After adding data type like suppose email

Google play ask two options

Collected This data is transmitted off the users device, either to you or a third party this includes data that is processed empherally, or stored for longer

Shared This data is transmitted to a third party,

either on off the users device.

Which one I should select if I am using firebase. Unable to understand hard language.

Sry for bad English.